# How can I insert values into a new table with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have 3 tables:

```
vehicle, line, brands.
```

I need to insert the values of vehicle into a new table `vehicleNew`, the problem is that table `vehicle` has these columns `vehicleId, lineName, brandsName`

The new table `vehicleNew` has `vehicleId, lineCode, brandsCode` how can I insert the values?

Comment: are `[lineName]` and `[lineCode]` the same datatype? Do they represent the same value? If so, you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into vehicleNew(vehicleId, lineCode, brandsCode)
    select vehicleId, lineName, brandsName from vehicle
```